# How to check if parameters/string contains a substring?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-frameworks

For example, if I submit a text. I want to check if it contains some string.
I am trying to check if submited text contains "@" or not. `params[:field].include? "@"` doesn't work in rails. It says undefined "include" method.

Comment: Are you sure `field` param is actually passed into controller? `nil.include?` indeed raises an error.

Comment: But it says undefined  method "include" for nil:NilClass

Comment: You get an error because you can't call `#include?` on `nil`. Like Marek said, you're most likely not receiving any data into your controller. If `params[:field]` is `nil` you will receive an error when calling `#include?`. Your issue here isn't the `#include?` method but the way data is submitted to your controller.

Comment: `params[:field].to_s.include? "@"`

Comment: Then How to pass parameters in controller ? Bnktkp

Comment: You should put the proper input in the form or pass it in the query string like `field=field_value`. And first of all, I guess, you need to learn about some basics.

Answer (score 2):

If `params[:field]` is nil, then you can't invoke `include?` on it, as it isn't a method defined in the NilClass class.

If what you want is to *to check if submitted text contains "@"*, you can use `=~`:

```
p { field: 'foo@bar' }[:field] =~ /@/ # 3
p nil =~ /@/ # nil
```

Comment: why not simple .to_s?

Comment: Who said no? You can, there are multiple ways to solve this problem, this is only one of all those.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case `params[:field]` is `nil` and the `#include?` method isn't available for `nil` objects. That's why you're getting an error.

Converting it to a string will make the object available for an `#include?` method call and remove the possibility of the object being `nil`:

```
params[:field].to_s.include? "@"
```

Comment: But it is not passing the parameter

Comment: ActionController::Parameters params will be still to accessible even if no parameters passed, params[:field] will give you nil and converting nil to string will make it "" empty string which  works for include? method.

Comment: I am creating a login system where login I'd will be username/email. My logic is if field contains '@' it will consider as email. Else username